# C# Apply regex only if property has value

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method

```
public static ProjectListItemViewModel CreateViewModel(P.Project project)
    {
        return new ProjectListItemViewModel
        {
            Id = project.Id,
            ExpectedResult = Regex.Replace(project.ExpectedResult, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", string.Empty).Trim().Length > 100 ? Regex.Replace(project.ExpectedResult, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", string.Empty).Trim().Substring(0, 100) + "..." : Regex.Replace(project.ExpectedResult, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", string.Empty).Trim(),
            Initiator = project.Initiator.FullName,
            Status = project.Status.Name,
            ProjectManager = project.ProjectManager != null ? project.ProjectManager.FullName  :"",
        };
    }
```

My question is how to apply Regex to ExpectedResult only if it is not null in the shortest possible way?

Comment: if (ExpectedResult!=null) ExpectedResult = Regex.Replace(project.ExpectedResult, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", string.Empty).Trim().Length > 100 ? Regex.Replace(project.ExpectedResult, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", string.Empty).Trim().Substring(0, 100) + "..." : Regex.Replace(project.ExpectedResult, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", string.Empty).Trim(),

Comment: Have you looked at the ternary operator? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change your style a bit, to only execute the regex once:

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public static ProjectListItemViewModel CreateViewModel(P.Project project)
{
    var rex = new Regex(@"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;");
    var expected = rex.Replace(project.ExpectedResult ?? string.Empty, string.Empty).Trim();

    return new ProjectListItemViewModel
    {
        Id = project.Id,
        ExpectedResult = expected.Length > 100 ? expected.Length.Substring(0, 100) : expected,
        Initiator = project.Initiator.FullName,
        Status = project.Status.Name,
        ProjectManager = project.ProjectManager != null ? project.ProjectManager.FullName : "",
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This:

`String Result =  !ExpectedResult ?? YourRegEx;`

In this way It directly applies if the value is not null.

This is not tested

where as this works fine in general c#

`String Result =  ExpectedResult ?? YourRegEx;`